# How to use WP_Query without breaking the main Query

Tags: wp-query

The [WP Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class can be used to make almost any imaginable query to the WP database. It's amazing.

But it's also used when WordPress is loaded, to run the main query for the current page request.

A common practice is to use `wp_reset_query()` and/or `wp_reset_postdata()`

But it's unclear when to use one or the other, or if they must be used at all. And I don't want to use them just in case but only when they are really needed.

So I would like to know what is the correct way to use the power of `WP Query` without breaking the main query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it's unclear when to use one or the other, or if they must be used at
> all

- If you've modified the global `$wp_query` variable (e.g. using [`query_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/) which should NOT actually be used), then use [`wp_reset_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/) to restore the variable back to the main query, i.e. so that the variable references or points to the main query again, and for example when you call `have_posts()`, it would check against the main query (whether it contains any posts) and not some other/custom query.

  ```php
  // This (should NOT be done and it) modifies the $wp_query global.
  query_posts( 'posts_per_page=2' );

  while ( have_posts() ) {
      the_post();
      the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
  }

  // This restores the $wp_query global back to the main query.
  wp_reset_query();
  ```
- If you've modified the global `$post` variable (e.g. using [`setup_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/setup_postdata/) or by calling the [`the_post()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/the_post/) in a *secondary/custom* `WP_Query` instance), then use [`wp_reset_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) to restore the variable back to the current post in the main query, so that for example calling `the_title()` would display the title of the second post in the main query and *not* the last post in a secondary query.

  ```php
  // Case 1: Calling the the_post() method in a custom WP_Query instance.

  $query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=2' );

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      // This modifies the $post global.
      $query->the_post();

      the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
  }

  // Restore the $post global back to the current post in the main query.
  wp_reset_postdata();

  // Case 2: Using setup_postdata().

  global $post;
  $posts = get_posts( 'posts_per_page=2' );

  foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      // This modifies the $post global.
      setup_postdata( $post );

      the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>' );
  }

  // Restore the $post global back to the current post in the main query.
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ```

  So in the two examples above, we only called `wp_reset_postdata()` and there's no need to call `wp_reset_query()` because neither of the two queries modified the main query (or the global `$wp_query` variable).

Therefore, if the `$wp_query` global is not modified, then no need to call `wp_reset_query()`, and if the `$post` global is not modified, then no need to call `wp_reset_postdata()`. I.e. Call just one of them.

### Additional Notes

- `query_posts()` will change the main query and is **not recommended**. Only use if absolutely necessary. Creating a new instance of `WP_Query` or [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) is preferred for secondary loops. If you would like to modify the main query, use the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action.
- In a `pre_get_posts` hook, you can use the [`is_main_query()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/is_main_query/) in the passed query object, to check whether the current query is the main query. Same goes with hooks like [`posts_orderby`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) which passes (if requested) the query object to the hook callbacks.
- The hooks in `WP_Query` also fires on the admin side (`wp-admin`), so you can use [`is_admin()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_admin/) to avoid changing the main query on the admin, unless of course if that is something you intended to do.

And I'm not exactly sure the main points in your question (or the exact kind of answer that you're looking for), but I hope this answer helps. :)

Comment: Genius! Thanks. I always use a new instance of WP Query or sometimes `get_posts()`, and I never "globalize" the results. So, according to the good information you provided, all is cool so far.

Comment: Awesome =) But sorry about the `the_title( '<h3>', '</h3>', );` - that extra comma (',') doesn't ( or it didn't in my case (PHP 7) ) cause an error, but I decided to revise my answer and corrected that mistake. :)